# Connect VMware Workstation 16 Player to the internet

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

Running VMware Workstation 16 Player on a Windows 10 Home (ver 20H2) host.
The virtual machine itself is Windows XP

The host is connected to the internet via wi-fi using the built in Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter and I have had connection to both google and Bing on IE, but **every** search result fails, suggesting firewall problems - but I have turned off firewall on both host and VM.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the XP Guest machine is set up with NAT networking. Bridged network won't work - no external router. Host Only is for internal only work. So use NAT.

Then you need a browser that works (old version of Chrome is about all that is left.

If you have IE on the XP machine, I am not sure if it works very well. I depend on Chrome for this. XP comes with IE and IE here gets to Google (I did test this) and you can download Chrome for XP at that point.

Restart the XP machine after changing the Network Settings in VMware.

I have a VMware XP Pro guest here, NAT connection and it works fine.  **Edit posted here** from XP Pro, Chrome for XP.